# Add estimated value for a post according to the number of words

Tags: plugins, count, meta-value, paypal, statistics

I have a blog where paid by 2 cents per word, need to add next to the word count one text value of statistics.

Anyone have any idea how to make this automatic multiplication along with the word count?

**example**: 27 words x $ 0.02 = $ 0.54

**The panel show:** Words: 27 | Estimated value: $ 0.54

**Show as the picture below**
[image: Estimated value: $ 0.54]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: hello, I search today. Sorry to be a little layman because I'm new to wordpress. I found several tutorials on adding the word count. But to account for the posting of value not found anything yet about it. Please give me a light if you know or indicate any tutorial where I can implement this feature. Grateful. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea for a starting point, by looking how the *word counting* is done in the [`/wp-admin/js/post.js`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/e510918b4e85cdbe26690fe00117e60819f5689a/wp-admin/js/post.js#L963-L1002) file:

```
/**
 * Testing word price calculations
 */
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', function()
{ ?><script>
    ( function( $ ) {
        $( function() {
            // Init
            var $content = $( '#content' ),
                $count = $( '#wp-word-count' ).find( '.word-count' ),
                total_price = 0,
                price_per_word = 0.02;

            // Out price updating function
            function wpse_update_price(){
                total_price = $count.html() * price_per_word;
                // Debug output
                console.log( 'Total price: ' + total_price );
            }

            // On keyup event 
            $content.on( 'input keyup', _.debounce( wpse_update_price, 1100 ) );
        } );
    } )( jQuery );
</script><?php
} );
```

Here we display the total price in the console log.

Hope you can adjust it further to your needs.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.
Put your code in edit-form-advanced.php file after the line:/// <td id="wp-word-count"><?php printf( __( 'Word count: %s' ), '<span class="word-count">0</span>' ); ?></td> /// 
It does not change anything in the admin page, maybe I'm doing something wrong, any idea?

Comment: Please don't modify the core files. You could try this in your `functions.php` file in the current theme directory or (better) create a plugin out of this. Then watch the console log e.g. F12 in Chrome, while you type the words @RodrigoSenna

Comment: I put the code in the theme functions.php file as you directed, so checked in Firebug he did not appear, see in the image. [link](http://mc.nse.me/images/01.jpg). You have any tips?

Comment: Note that this will not (currently) show up in the HTML of the page, just in the  "Console" debug window. In the screenshot I can see that you're viewing the "HTML" tab, try to click on the "Console" tab on the left, instead. Then the next step for you would be to inject the price value back into the page via jQuery  @RodrigoSenna

Comment: works, see the image /// [link](http://mc.nse.me/images/02.jpg) /// could give me an example of how to inject the page the price value via jQuery?

Comment: great, I think there are many examples around regarding HTML injection in jQuery, e.g. with methods like `appendTo()`. That should hopfully get you going. Also take a look at the core example (i.e. the  `tinymce-editor-init` event handler) , to see how you can display the price value before you start typing. @RodrigoSenna